# Google charts, problematically get trend line value for first and last points

Tags: javascript, charts

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);
                    function drawCurveTypes() {
                        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        data.addColumn('date', 'Period');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'AveragePricePaid');
                        for (i = 0; i < rollingyears; i++) {
                            data.addRows([
                                [new Date(Fperioddata[i]), Faveragedata[i]]
                              ]);
                        }
                        var options = {
                            title: 'Average Price Paid (Rolling Year)',
                            hAxis: { title: 'Rolling Year' },
                            vAxis: { title: 'Average Price Paid' },
                            //legend: 'none',
                            height: 300,
                            width: 520,
                            pointSize: 10,
                            pointShape: 'square',
                            trendlines: { 0: { color: 'green', pointSize: 2, pointShape: 'square', showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} }
                        };
```

The above code works and provides a graph with a trendline on. I need to be able to get the value of the first and last trendline point.

I need to get these without having to click on the graph. Ideally at the same time the graph is generated. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: because of the nature of the API call, I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem by programatically calculate the trendline instead of using the built-in function.